# Two Source Column needs to be compared against One Target in SSIS Lookup

Tags: ssis

I have following Scenario

a. Oledb Source is fetching data from a remote Server.
b. Data is being passed to Lookup.
c. Here i need to Compare Two Source Columns with One Detination Column

I am not getting how i can do this? Should i use two Lookup transformations, If yes then How?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing a nuance of your question, the lookup of a single value is the same as a lookup using multiple columns.

On the left (source) side, drag the column to its mate on the right (lookup) side. Repeat until you've matched all the fields that need to be matched.

Optionally, select the output columns you need.